# Call to NtQueryInformationProcess returns STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION error

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, window-handles, ntdll

I'm trying to query all the handles in the current process. For that, first I'm trying to call [NtQueryInformationProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationprocess), which after 2 consecutive calls ends up throwing a STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xC0000005) error code.

My c# code is as follows:

```
 public class Main
    {

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        public struct PROCESS_HANDLE_INFORMATION
        { // ProcessInfoClass 0x33
            public IntPtr Handle;
            public IntPtr HandleCount;
            public IntPtr PointerCount;
            public ulong GrantedAccess;
            public ulong ObjectTypeIndex;
            public ulong HandleAttributes;
            public ulong Reserved;
        }
        
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        public struct PROCESS_HANDLE_SNAPSHOT_INFORMATION
        { // ProcessInfoClass 0x33
            public ulong NumberOfHandles;
            public ulong Reserved;
            public IntPtr Handles;
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

        [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int NtQueryInformationProcess(IntPtr processHandle, uint processInformationClass, ref IntPtr processInformation, int processInformationLength, ref int returnLength);

        [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern void RtlZeroMemory(IntPtr Destination, int length);

        private const uint CNST_PROCESS_HANDLE_INFORMATION = 0x33;
        
        public static void doThings()
        {
            unsafe
            {
                int handle_info_size = 0;
                int nLength = 0;
                IntPtr ptrHandleData = IntPtr.Zero;
                try
                {
                    int status = NtQueryInformationProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), CNST_PROCESS_HANDLE_INFORMATION, ref ptrHandleData, handle_info_size, ref nLength);
                    while (status != 0)
                    {
                        handle_info_size = nLength;
                        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptrHandleData);
                        ptrHandleData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
                        RtlZeroMemory(ptrHandleData, nLength);
                        status = NtQueryInformationProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), CNST_PROCESS_HANDLE_INFORMATION, ref ptrHandleData, handle_info_size, ref nLength);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptrHandleData);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

The first two times I call NtQueryInformationProcess it returns STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH (0xC0000004), which seems fine since first you need to figure out the required buffer length. After those two calls, I guess I have finally obtained the right buffer length but from there it only throws STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION errors and the handles information is never successfully retrieved.

Comment: `ref IntPtr processInformation` - shouldn't this be simply `IntPtr processInformation`

Comment: Are you sure you're heading in the right direction here? The only time this information is stable and generally useful is when the process you're querying is suspended - but that's obviously not true if you're querying within your own process. If you got this information, what actual *problem* do you think it would help you to solve?

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/microsoft/win32/NativeMethods.cs,1301

Comment: Quote from docs *"NtQueryInformationProcess may be altered or unavailable in future versions of Windows. Applications should use the alternate functions listed in this topic."*

Comment: @KlausGütter that was the issue, thank you.